# ¿Cómo sustituir correctamente los elementos de una matriz en java?

Tags: java, array

```
    public static void Modifica(int[][]matriz,int longitudBloque, int columna, int dificultad) {
    int fila=inicioBloque(matriz,columna);
    int filaConstante=fila;
    int finalBloque=inicioBloque(matriz,columna)+ContadorElementosBloque(columna,matriz)-1;
    System.out.print(finalBloque);
    System.out.print(fila);
    System.out.print(longitudBloque);
    for(int i=0; i<longitudBloque; i++) {
        if(filaConstante==1) {
            matriz[fila][columna]= numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
            fila++; 
        } else {
            //for (int j=0;j<longitudBloque;j++){
            while(finalBloque>longitudBloque){
                matriz[finalBloque][columna]=matriz[finalBloque-longitudBloque][columna];
                finalBloque--;


            }
            if(longitudBloque==3){
                matriz[2][columna]=numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
                matriz[3][columna]=numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
                matriz[4][columna]=numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
            }
            if(longitudBloque==4){
                matriz[2][columna]=numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
                matriz[3][columna]=numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
                matriz[4][columna]=numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
                matriz[5][columna]=numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
            }
            if(longitudBloque==5){
                matriz[2][columna]=numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
                matriz[3][columna]=numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
                matriz[4][columna]=numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
                matriz[5][columna]=numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
                matriz[6][columna]=numero_aleatorio(dificultad);
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Este es mi código para ello pero lo que sucede es que bajan todos los elementos excepto el último.
Os dejo un ejemplo:
[image: error]

En las coordenadas 6,2 y 8,2 de la primera matriz se crea una columna de tres 1 consecutivos. Lo óptimo sería que esos tres 1 se "eliminasen", los elementos de arriba bajaran para "rellenar" y los 3 de arriba se convirtieran en aleatorios, pero el resultado es la matriz de abajo y el problema reside en que todos bajan pero el último elemento del bloque no se sustituye.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tu código no comila, te recomiendo leer el artículo [mcve]

Comment: Va a ser difícil ayúdarte porque hay métodos que no están publicados. Entiendo lo que intentas hacer, pero lo único que veo 'extraño' es que a la variable **finalBloque**  al final restas 1. ¿Que valores deberían tomar esas variables?

Answer (score -1):

Esta un poco complejo tu código, pero te sugiero que analices lo siguiente:

```
public void llenarMatriz(int filasMatriz, int colMatriz){
 int matriz [][] = new int[filasMatriz][colMatriz];
 int filas = matriz.length;
 int columnas = matriz[0].length;

  for(int c = 0; c < columnas; c++){ // recorremos las columnas primero
        for(int f = 0; f < filas; f++){ // recorremos las filas
            matriz[f][c] = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*10);
        }
  }

    System.out.println("Mostrando elementos:");
  for(int c = 0; c < columnas; c++){ // recorremos las columnas primero
        for(int f = 0; f < filas; f++){ // recorremos las filas
            System.out.print(matriz[f][c]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
  }


}
```

Comment: Eso ya lo tengo en un método, lo que necesito es que sustituya los elementos de la columna formada y descubrir porqué se produce el error antes mencionado.

Comment: No tengo claro como seria esta sustitución. Aclara un poco mas para darte un código mas preciso y así poder apoyarte. Saludos.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te podrían votar negativamente porque no esperaste a entender la pregunta antes de contestar.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3217/342)